# WCF: How to generate WSDL file based on XSD files and service contract?

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

I've looked at xsd.exe, wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe utilities in order to find the way to generate WSDL file based on XSD files and service contract but can't see the solution.

The service contract is something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessageManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ConvertToUpper(string text);
}

public class MessageManager : IMessageManager
{
    public string ConvertToUpper(string text)
    {
        return text.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

I appreciate if someone could suggest how to do that in any way.

Thank you in advance.

Goran

Comment: What do you mean by `service contract` ?

Comment: WSDL describes hosted service, not just a contract. Contract is not enough. Moreover your sample doesn't show how is it related to XSD files.

Comment: I mean on something like this: [ServiceContract] public interface IMessageManager { [OperationContract] string ConvertToUpper(string text); } Please, see edited starting post.

Comment: So, we got a bunch of XSD files from our client they were generated. And we know how service contract should look like. XSD files describes the data. That's our input. We should generate WSDL file and use it programmatically in order to invoke WCF service, which contract (form) is known. That's our task.

Comment: @hugh: Yes. I've already did it and it worked. But we need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand you questions , I am assuming that you are needing to use XSD to extract data contract , for this try out -

http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know that tool, tried it and it works. But, everything should be done programmatically.

Comment: Looking at your service contract the input and output are strings which does not require data contracts. Is your service contract returning data represented by xsd if not then to consume the service you do not need to convert xsd, then again I might have misinterpreted the question.